# JQuery: Change body css attribute left on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get my website to scale its width when the window size is changed.

JQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $("body").width();
    if(w-810 < 0) {
        $("body").css("Left","0px");
    }
    else {
        var width = w.toString() + "px";
        $("body").css("Left",width); 
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #eeeeee;
position: relative;
left: 20%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="scripts\jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts\myJavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
....
<body class="body">
```

One thing I have noticed, if I select the body by class (change in jquery to "#body"), it always defaults to 0px for the width.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the body element by a class, you must use the `'.body'` selector. If you want to get elements with their id, use `'#body'`

Try to put the CSS in lowercase, better passing in an object as parameter. Moreover, try also to "cache" the body element in order to prevent several, unnecessary querys to the DOM tree:

```
var body = $('.body');

$(window).resize(function() {
    var w = body.width();

    if (w-810 < 0) {
        w = "0";
    }

    body.css({ "left" : w + "px" });
});
```

Comment: This is definitely more efficient.  However, my page still doesn't scale correctly.   I am doing all my work offline now, having my html/css/js files in a folder.  Would that effect my output?

Comment: Found out javascript does not work offline.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JoeG You're welcome :) I've also changed the `w = "0"` assignment for `w = 0` which is better because the type of the var `w` is always the same. This way, we improve the style of the code and it's better for the efficiency, because the "hidden class" of the object is always a number, not a number first and then a string later.

Answer (score 0):

The body class is `'.body'`, not `'#body'`