# Changing the body with jQuery when resize the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the body content when I resize the windows, but after 2 hours searching and trying, I get nothing.

This is my last jQuery code:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width<=320){
        changeHTML();
    }
});

    var changeHTML=function(){
        alert("wow");
        //$('body').load('../index2.html');
    }
```

The "index2.html" is something like this:

```
<div>
A lot of stuff
</div>
```

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013758/jquery-change-body-css-attribute-left-on-window-resize

Comment: `$(window).width` should be `$(window).width()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(window).width` is incorrect, as `width()` is a method. Use `$(window).width()` instead.

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/By8K5/)***

Comment: Since you had beat me to it, I added my fiddle to your answer. =D

Comment: I tried it in JsFiddle and watched the error the browser was throwing. Actually I didn't share that fiddle. :) Thanks for the addition